# Выбор языка приложения iphone ?

Tags: xcode, objective-c, mac, iphone, c++

Нужно чтобы при загрузке приложения выскакивало меню выбора языка. Само приложение при загрузке подключается к интернету и обновляет информацию (это происходит каждый час). 
Я не писал под iphone, соответственно у меня вопрос как лучше сделать ? то есть я создаю отдельный xib с выбором локали ? он должен зависеть от MainWindow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Зачем это делать при загрузке? Если локализация реализована стандартным для ios приложений, то автоматически подгрузится та локаль, которая выбрана в системе. Если выбрана та, которой нету, то подгрузится английская по дефолту.

2) Если хочешь сделать выбор языка не стандартным способом, то лучше сделать отдельный пункт в настройках, а не так, чтобы при загрузке выскакивало меню выбора языка (imho).

3) Именно выскакивающее меню можно сделать таким образом (без использования ARC):

В `UIViewController'e` в методе `viewWillAppear:` можно проверить выбран ли язык, и если не выбран, то сделать следущее:

```
`UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Choose the language" message:@"Tap to prefered language" delegate:<Твой viewControler или другой объект, которого ты назначил делегатом> cancelButtonTitle:@"Default" otherButtonTitles:@"Russian",@"English",@"French", nil];`
`[av show];`
`[av release],av=nil;`
```

В объекте назначенном делегатом следует реализовать 2 метода `- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex`  и `alertViewCancel:`

4) После загрузки в `UIViewController'а`, в методе `viewWillAppear:` можно проверить выбран ли язык, и если не выбран, то  вызвать другой ViewController(я бы вызвал UITableViewControler со списком возможных языков) где выбирается язык([Источник](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111)):

```
`- (void)add:(id)sender {
    // Create the root view controller for the navigation controller
    // The new view controller configures a Cancel and Done button for the
    // navigation bar.
    RecipeAddViewController *addController = [[RecipeAddViewController alloc] init];
    // Configure the RecipeAddViewController. In this case, it reports any
    // changes to a custom delegate object.
    addController.delegate = self;
    // Create the navigation controller and present it.
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
    initWithRootViewController:addController];
    [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion: nil];
}`
```